# How to restructure SQL query so that I can write/refer them easily

Tags: sql

I have following queries.

```
Select * from (
  Select a, b, c, d, from t1
  Union
  Select a, b, c, d from t2
) where a is not null and order by b.
```

Now I have to fetch data from another table based on above result set.

```
    Select * from (Select * from (
        Select a, b, c, d, from t1
        Union
        Select a, b, c, d from t2
        ) 

     where a is not null and order by b) 

as tempT1 left outer join t3 on tempT1.a = t3.a
```

I have to further use this result set to form another select query. So, writing in above style will be complex with time. And with time this query will be complex to read.

How to make it simple? Can I dump partial result to another table?

Comment: You seem to be mixing query syntax with english used in question. Can you please correct that? also, please tag specific technology details as applicable.

Comment: You have at least one syntax error in your query. (Depending in dbms used... Which one are you using?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `temporary` tables. Rewrite your queries as

```
Select * into #tempResult1 from (
Select a, b, c, d, from t1
Union
Select a, b, c, d from t2
)  where a is not null and order by b
```

Now for next query, use above `temp table` as

```
Select * into #tempResult2 
from #tempResult1
left outer join t3 on tempT1.a = t3.a
```

Now instead of writing this query, just use `#tempResult2`.

```
select * from #tempResult2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create views that will replace these *inner SELECTs*
From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) :
*"In SQL, a view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement.
A view contains rows and columns, just like a real table. The fields in a view are fields from one or more real tables in the database.
You can add SQL functions, WHERE, and JOIN statements to a view and present the data as if the data were coming from one single table."*

Document them so you wont get lost and that's it...

Comment: CTE's can only be used once. Temporary tables are a pain. Views is the best solution given the limited explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use **Comman Table expression or Temp Table or Table Variable**

```
with cte as
(
 Select a, b, c, d from t1
 Union
 Select a, b, c, d from t2
)
,
cte2 as
(
select * cte where a is not null and order by b
)
select * from cte2 c left outer join t3 on c.a = t3.a
```

**Using Temp Table**

```
select * into #temp1
from 
(
 Select a, b, c, d from t1
     Union
     Select a, b, c, d from t2
)

select * into #temp2 from #temp1 where a is not null and order by b

select * from temp2 c left outer join t3 on c.a = t3.a
```

Comment: please Give Me Error..@jarlh

Comment: For example the "d, from". (I know it's just copied from the question!)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server, You could simplify something like below. Not a compiled version. But you could use this as pseudo code.

```
with cte as
(
        Select a, b, c, d from t1 where a is not null
        Union
        Select a, b, c, d from t2 where a is not null
 ) 

select * from cte tempT1 left outer join t3 on tempT1.a = t3.a order by tempT1.b
```

Comment: what does you select statement Mean..?? you define two table with out separate them..!!Don't you think it will cause ERROR..

Comment: Which line you are talking about? which table you are asking about? your question was not clear. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You have some wrong SQL syntax too. Try:

```
;
WITH    Q1
            AS ( SELECT   a ,
                        b ,
                        c ,
                        d
                FROM     t1
                UNION
                SELECT   a ,
                        b ,
                        c ,
                        d
                FROM     t2
                ),
        Q2
            AS ( SELECT   *
                FROM     Q1
                )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Q2 tempT1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON tempT1.a = t3.a
    WHERE   a IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY b
```